# chef docker-api cookbook fails, error malformed header

Tags: docker, chef-infra, docker-api, malformed, chef-client

chef-clients are unable to run **docker cookbook api** commands like docker_registry, docker_image and docker_container. The docker cli commands in the recipe are working fine and are able to connect and pull from dockerhub and private docker registry hosted on Nexus. chef-client error states **“malformed header”**, no new changes were made to chef-server, chef-client, cookbooks or any of the versions. Tried upgrading the chef-client and docker cookbook to a newer version but still same error. This happened to both dev and prod (separate chef-servers for both)nodes at almost the same time and clients started failing. About 40 nodes failing at sync with the same error “malformed header”.

****chef-client = v15.1.36****

****docker cookbook = v8.0.1****

Here is the error,

"status": "failure",
"run_list": "["recipe[testinator::ufw]","recipe[testinator::smb]"]",
"total_res_count": "33",
"data": {
"exception": {
"class": "#<Excon::Error::Socket: docker_image[dperson/samba] (testinator::smb line 360) had an error: Excon::Error::Socket: malformed header (Excon::Error::ResponseParse)>",
"message": "docker_image[dperson/samba] (testinator::smb line 360) had an error: Excon::Error::Socket: malformed header (Excon::Error::ResponseParse)",
"backtrace":

Comment: You can use `EXCON_DEBUG=true chef-client` to dump more logs

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Excon 0.108.0, which is used by Chef. Ref: [malformed header (Excon::Error::ResponseParse) in version 0.108.0 · Issue #845 · excon/excon](https://github.com/excon/excon/issues/845)